# Detecting single CJK character

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, cjk

I have a string that could be either an english word or a single CJK character. I am guaranteed that this string is in UTF-8 encoding. I am working inside of a perl script.

The higher level problem is I have an array of strings like the one described above. I am doing a join " " @array. I want to know to not add the space when its CJK.

So for CJK I will just do join "" @array.

I have looked around but can't find this exact question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the regular expression `\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}`. This is a Unicode Block (as opposed to Unicode Scripts, which are also supported by Perl, but don't seem to match your problem description).

There are some other candidate blocks, like the Extension A and the Radicals Supplement. [Here's a full list](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block).

Comment: That worked great! I didn't know about Unicode blocks. What do you mean by your qualifier though? Is this in danger of not recognizing some CJK characters? Or what does the Unicode classes mean?

Comment: @YGomez: Glad it helped. When you wrote that comment, I already updated the answer and removed "classes" from the text. Have a look at the link I added, it explains everything pretty well.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I will look through the list of blocks to make sure all possible inputs are covered. Thank you for the link.